# MySQL Use Single Row as Where In

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following row.

```
+-----------+-----------+-----------+
| A_USER_ID | B_USER_ID | C_USER_ID |
+-----------+-----------+-----------+
|         4 |         1 |         2 |
+-----------+-----------+-----------+
```

The reason I have the data in this format is that I am running a cross join to generate all the triplets in my data.

I now need to retrieve the user details for each of these IDs. I'm looking for something like the following.

```
SELECT * FROM USERS WHERE USER_ID IN ([existing-query])
```

I'm not sure how to do this since MySQL doesn't have a rotate.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you can use `exists` for this:

```
select u.*
from users u
where exists (select 1
              from <existing query> q
              where u.user_id in (q.a_user_id, q.b_user_id, q.c_user_id)
             );
```